# How to deal with thread in background processing java spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, request

I want to download file after query but the time is too long, so my company said I should let the process in background.

For that I create thread when user call method, it will generate file and send to email of customer.

But the problem is about my thread, I also test function for sendemaildownload (it also includes the function which I use to query), I'm quite sure this problem from the way I create the thread.

This is what it says to me when I'm logging the error on creating the thread:

> Exception in thread "Nathan-Transportation1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

Is there any way to fix it? I want to understand why it happend when I create my thread pool.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Edit your question to include your code, and the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to show image when i try push it on it still change to link

Comment: Don't use an image -- copy and paste your code into the question as text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using @Async annotation.
For more information see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async)

Comment: I think that's what i need, i should use async not executor.excecute or i have to choose one of them

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that you are attempting to access request-scoped data (for example, request attributes) outside of the context of an HTTP request.

You can try the following solutions to this problem:

1. To expose the current request and make it accessible to your code,
   use a RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter.
2. To execute tasks in a background thread, use Spring's TaskExecutor interface, which will handle the necessary context management for you.

Here are some links that may be of interest to you:

- [RequestContextListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextListener.html)
- [RequestContextFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/RequestContextFilter.html)
- [TaskExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/TaskExecutor.html)